# Operator if int value was a multiple of a specific value call a method

Tags: c#

I need help in knowing what is the right operator when I'd like to call a method if the int was a multiple of a specific value (Ex. 10, 20, 30, etc) in the loop.

Ex.

```
int firstInt = 0;
int secondInt = 10;
for (int firstInt = 0; firstInt < 100; firstInt++)
{
    if(firstInt "value has increased by secondInt") {
        "call the method"
    }
    // do something else for each iteration
}
```

Comment: Note:  "bare with me" means "get naked with me".  I'm sure you meant to say "bear with me"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you supplied the specific scenario that you are facing; but I *think* what you're trying to ask is... **How do I get my program to do something within a loop; but rather than *every* time, just every *n* times, where *n* is a constant?**

If that's the case then you need to make use of modular arithmethic. I'm having to assume/imagine the loop (which isn't in the question; but should be) to give this example...

```
for (int firstInt = 0; firstInt < 100; firstInt++)
{
   const int secondInt = 10;

   if((firstInt % secondInt) == 0)
   {
       // "call the method"
   }
}
```

Basically this is saying: if the `firstInt` value is exactly divisible by `secondInt`, then it will call the method.

You may want to read about [the modulus operator (a.k.a. Remainder operator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator).